# add width animation to a sprite in cocos2D

Tags: xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone, width, sprite

so I would like to know if in cocos2D it is possible to add an animation to the width of a sprite with actions.For example my sprite's width is 100 and its width goes to 200 with animation .(just the width no the height)Thank you :) sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can use action for this.

```
CCSprite *spr = nil;//your sprite
CGFloat startingWidth = 100;
CGFloat finalWidth = 200;

id action = [CCPropertyAction actionWithDuration:2 key:@"scaleX" from:1 to:finalWidth / startingWidth];
[spr runAction:action];
```

Comment: we just have to replace it by CCActionTween

Comment: yes, CCActionTween or CCPropertyAction. It depends on cocos2d version, you are using.http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:actions_special